# Saving a Dictionary(Of String, Int16()) into a PostgreSQL cell

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, visual-studio, npgsql

I have a `Dictionary(of String, INT16()).` This dictionary represents analog values from a measurement. I want to store this dictionary into one cell of a PostgreSQL database. I am using Npgsql.

I was searching a Long time, but I have no idea how to do that.

My thought was to serialize the dictionary and save it as an array, but i am not sure if this is the correct way.

Is there anybody out there, who can help me in this matter?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Not a good idea to have such DB schema, that needs to store list in one field. So serialization solution sounds good in that case.

Comment: What would be a common way? To save a file with serialized data, or to save serialized data as a bytestream? In the end I think it is the same. I am a noob in this matter.

Comment: of course byte array. Why you even need a file.

Comment: @ManfredSinger please take another look at my sample, I added a full sample code of how to implement this in pg sql.

Comment: Could somebody explain me, why I am blocked from asking questions? What was wrong with it? OK, in my first post I had no formatting. This was changed. But why I am blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [CREATE TYPE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtype.html)

```
CREATE TYPE StringIntPairType AS (k string,v int);
```

UPDATE:
Here is a full example of how to accomplish this from pg sql

Define the element type of the dictionary

```
CREATE TYPE StringIntPairType AS (k text,v int);
```

Create a sample table. note that the collection column is marked '[]' at the end

```
CREATE TABLE CollectionsTables
(
  Id SERIAL UNIQUE,
  Collection  StringIntPairType[],
  Description TEXT,
  TS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
)
```

Inserts a single record with two dictionary elements

```
INSERT INTO CollectionsTables(Collection,Description) VALUES
(
    array
    [
       ('Test1',1)::StringIntPairType,
       ('Test2',2)::StringIntPairType
    ],
    'Description1'
);
```

Inserts another single record with two dictionary elements

```
INSERT INTO CollectionsTables(Collection,Description) VALUES
        (
            array
            [
               ('TestA',30)::StringIntPairType,
               ('TestB',40)::StringIntPairType
            ],
            'Description2'
        );
```

Note that this is regular table just like any other table

```
SELECT * FROM CollectionsTables
```

Here is some more advanced select.

```
SELECT Collection[1].k,Description FROM CollectionsTables
```

First column: The key of the first dictionary value
Second column: the description column

Comment: This would only allow storing a single string/int *pair*, not a dictionary (or collection of pairs) as asked above.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I can clearly understand that the type suggested represent a single element in the collection. luckily pg supports arrays...

Comment: @ShayRojansky for your convenience I added a full sample code including the usage of arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html), and even apply [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) on it.
This may or may not be a good approach, it depends on what you need to do with the data and how your system is built.

Comment: I have a datagridview. Every line of it represents a measurement run. I have also a chartview. If I make a doubleclick to a specific row, the chartview is showing the specific analog values of the selected run. This values as mentioned as dictionary should be saved within one cell of the corresponding database row.

Answer (score 0):

While the JSON (or JSONB) datatype should be the preferred answer as mentioned above, you also have the option of using [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html). The disadvantage is that hstore only stores strings, so your ints wouldn't be typed.